# Using a LabelValueBean properly

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2, ognl

I have a variable:

```
private ArrayList<LabelValueBean> circleNameIdList;
```

inside my `Action` class where it's value get populated.

I want to display the label in my drop-down in JSP and when one label is selected, the corresponding value to that particular label in `circleNameIdList` to be passed to the server.
Eg.: If label: `NewYork` is selected then it's corresponding `id = 5`, is sent to the server.

How can I achieve this?

Up till now I was doing like this in JSP:

```
<s:select list="#session.circleNameIdList" label="Select Circle:" name="circleNameIdList" id="circleNameIdList"></s:select>
```

However, it display is not correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see you are using a `LableValueBean` to populate and show a dropdown. It's a former bean used at last to display a list of objects. In Struts2 you're no longer required such a helper bean. You can display a list of objects by specifying a key field that would hold a unique value of the selected option and a value to be shown as the option text. For example if your object

```
public class Circle {
   private Long id;
   //getter and setter here

  private String name;
  //getter and setter here
}
```

and you have in the action class

```
private List<Circle> circleNameIdList;
//getter and setter here

/**
 * Hold the selected value
 */
private Long circleId;
//getter and setter here
```

then

```
<s:select id="circleNameIdListID" label="Circle:" name="circleId" 
  list="circleNameIdList"   listKey="id" listValue="name" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Circle"/>
```

could be used to show the dropdown.

Comment: Circle in my case is not an object. My circleNameIdList was ArrayList<LabelValueBean>. So basically kinda map with types strings <String circleName, String circleId>. Now, I want to display names in drop down and get id in action class. How can i do it????

Comment: Add/replace these attributes `listKey="value" listValue="label"`.