# Drop-Down in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I have a map with key-value pairs. I want to display the key on a drop-down and value to be sent to server for identifying what is selected.

I am using Struts2. I tried putting the `Map` in `<s:select>` tags `list`, however it shows the values in the dropdown.

Comment: ca u provide sample code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `listKey` and `listValue` attributes of `<s:select>` tag to get properties from list of objects.

In order to swap keys and values in map put *value* in `listKey` and *key* in `listValue`.

```
<s:select list="someMap" listKey="value" listValue="key"/>
```

Comment: @SiddharthTrikha: This also answers your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20417711/1700321.

Answer (score 2):

As far as you know the dropdown in Struts 2 can be used with `List` or any other collection like `Map`. It uses OGNL to retrieve the values for the options text and values.

The difference from the `List` is that the `Map` is converted via `entrySet()` and iterated to get `Map.Entry` element for the select option.

This object you can use to map a `key` and `value` for your dropdown. It has `getKey()` and `getValue()` methods that is useful to OGNL to populate a dropdown. The first is used to populate a `value` attribute, which is submitted to the action if it's selected, and a second fills an option's text.

If your dropdown shows values, then you map them wrong. The values should be mapped as a keys of the `Map`, and display texts as values.