# Struts 2 - Setting the label attribute for options in a select tag

Tags: java, struts2

For legacy code support reasons, I need to create a select tag in struts 2 and also need the label attribute in the resulting option list to match the value. An example probably will explain it better.

The generated code should look something like this:

```
<select>
  <option label="Darth Vader">Darth Vader</option>
  <option label="Luke Skywalker">Luke Skywalker</option>
  <!-- etc -->
</select>
```

My struts markup is as follows:

```
<s:select headerKey="-1" headerValue="" list="users" size="4" multiple="true" 
      tabindex="2" listKey="key" listValue="value"/>
```

The "users" collection is of type Map. Essentially, I want the value of each entry of the map to also be the label attribute for the option elements that struts creates. I've tried using the listLabelKey and label attributes provided by Strut's select tag with no luck. Is there an easy way to accomplish this that I'm just missing?

EDIT

I have some legacy javascript code that dynamically selects/unselects dropdown elements and relies on the label attribute on option being explicitly filled in. Using the listKey and listValue attributes simply generates the following HTML.

```
<select>
  <option>Darth Vader</option>
  <option>Luke Skywalker</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Use `listKey` and `listValue`. `~Label` is for localized version of field label.

Comment: @AleksandrM that should be the answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drop-Down in Struts 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20419844/drop-down-in-struts-2)

Comment: How do you use these attributes? Show your `<s:select>` tag.

Comment: I've updated the markup to exactly what I'm trying.

Comment: What is in the `users` map?

Comment: It's an <Integer, String>, the key being the user's ID and the value being their name.

Comment: And why do you use id as select key if you want it to be the value ?