# Displaying Map keys on struts2 autocompleter tag

Tags: jsp, struts2, jstl, ognl, struts2-jquery

I've been struggling for a while with the `autocompleter` tag using `struts2 jquery plugin`.

I've been able to use it on a simple way, just retrieving `String` lists from a database, but now I wondered if I could fetch a `HashMap` from my action and display the user **keys only**.

The response comming from the action is successfull, I can see on my chrome dev tools that the action is returning a `JSON` containing my `Map`. However, the autocompleter **displays te values** instead of the keys, which I really want, as I'm trying to list some addresses to the user and had used them as keys on my `Map`, whose values are just identifiers for each address.

This example should ilustrate what my `Map` looks like. It's the response I'm getting from my action call when the user writes 'Ho':

```
{"addressesList":{"Home":"-20","Hotel":"-4","Hooters":"-2"}}
```

However, when the user starts writing in the autocompleter, it keeps showing the values (-20, -4, -2), which are not representative to the user.

I know I could just reverse the way I do it and store the identifiers as keys and the addresses' names as values, but I'm curious about this and really wanted to learn how to force my autocompleter tag to show the keys instead of the `Map` values. That easy way is not a solution for me.

I believe this question has more to do with JSTL / OGNL than Struts2 tags and I find it interesting as I couldn't find googling any example on how to do this.

## My autocompleter tag inside the JSP

```
<sj:autocompleter 
        id="addresses"
        name="selectedAddress"
        list="addressesList"
        href="%{findAddresses}"
        delay="50"
        loadMinimumCount="2"/>
```

That `addressesList` is the `HashMap` inside my action.
Tried endless combinations using also `listValue` and `listKey` properties, like setting `listKey = addressesList.keySet()` and things like that, but sadly none worked out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drop-Down in Struts 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20419844/drop-down-in-struts-2)

Comment: Hello @AleksandrM , the accepted answer doesn't work out for me, It displays nothing when adding `listKey="key"` and `listValue="value"` to the tag declaration I posted on the question. This was one of the many things I tried.

Comment: Sorry @AleksandrM , I tried and it keeps showing the map values, doesn't show the keys. On last comment I was mistaken, it indeed works but doesn't seem to do anything, results are still the same

Comment: What exactly you're receiving from the server? The snippet you've shown doesn't hold array.

Comment: But you want to swap them, no?

Comment: I showed only part of the response, it's something like this:
`{"addressesList":{"Home":"-20","Hotel":"-4","Hooters":"-2"},"bound":false, .......... }` it's got more properties coming with the `Map`. I want to show the user the keys, not the values. It's currently showing the values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118520/discussion-between-jorgegrc-and-aleksandr-m).