# How to populate Struts2 dropdown menu?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am using `Struts2` and I am trying to populate the drop down using `<s:select>` tag but for some reason I don't see anything in the drop down. In the back end the list `wsAuditConfig` is getting populated with the values but it is not showing up in the drop down.

### Action

```
private List<String> wsAuditConfig;

public void prepare() throws Exception {
    AppConfigClient appConfigClient = ( AppConfigClient ) AppContext.getBean( Constants.SPRING_BEAN_CMS_APP_CONFIG_CLIENT );
    String appCode = ( String ) System.getProperty( Constants.SPRING_BEAN_EIS_APP_CODE );

    List<AppConfig> list = new ArrayList<>();
    wsAuditConfig = new ArrayList<>();

    GetAppConfigServiceRequest request = appConfigClient.getGetAppConfigServiceRequest();
    request.setParameters( appConfigClient.getAppConfigRequestParameters( appCode, null ) );
    request.setAccepts( ContentType.JSON );

    GetAppConfigServiceResponse response = appConfigClient.get( request );
    if( response != null && response.getEntity() != null ) {
        list = response.getEntity().getConfig();
        for( AppConfig appConfig : list ) {
            if( appConfig.getConfigCode().equals( Constants.APP_WS_AUDIT_CONFIG ) ) {
                wsAuditConfig.add( appConfig.getKeyName1() );
            }
        }
    }
    this.records = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

#### JSP

```
<s:form action="viewWSAuditXml" namespace="/eismain/cmswsaudit/view" name="wsAudit">
    <s:select name="wsName" headerValue="" headerKey="" list="wsAuditConfig" listKey="wsName" listValue="wsName" key="ws.audit.view.select" onchange="wsAudit.submit();" cssStyle="min-width: 220px;"/>
</s:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dropdown should be populated in the `prepare()` method, for which the action class should implement `Preparable` and there should be `prepare` interceptor in the action config.

A getter is required

```
private List<String> wsAuditConfig;
public List<String> getWsAuditConfig() { return wsAuditConfig; }
```

Since it's a list of strings the element of the list doesn't have a key or value properties. So it could be used without `listKey` and `listValue`.

```
<s:form action="viewWSAuditXml" namespace="/eismain/cmswsaudit/view" name="wsAudit">
    <s:select name="wsName" headerValue="" headerKey="" list="wsAuditConfig" key="ws.audit.view.select" onchange="wsAudit.submit();" cssStyle="min-width: 220px;"/>
</s:form>
```

---

If you want to list objects in the dropdown you should use typed list and the key and value provided similar how in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20421870/573032) answer.

Comment: I removed the extra properties and it started working. Thanks Roman C.

Answer (score 0):

What is `wsName`? Since you have list of String change select as following and it shold work.

```
<s:select name="wsName" headerValue="" headerKey="" list="wsAuditConfig"   onchange="wsAudit.submit();" cssStyle="min-width: 220px;"/>
```